# Create custom event in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have created a custom event for Google Calendar, because I need it to notify me on the penultimate day of the month.

This is what I have done so far:

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR VERSION:2.0 BEGIN:VEVENT RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSETPOS=-2;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR SUMMARY:Nómina DESCRIPTION: DTSTART:20230801T080000 DTEND:20230801T080000 SEQUENCE:0 END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR`

I'm looking for a way to remove any holidays there may be.

Directly I know that it cannot be done (that is, say the holidays), but indirectly the same thing can be done: it would be to say, for example

If January 20 is a holiday, then establish a period from January 1 to 19 and another from January 21 onwards.

Searching for information, I found this:

https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-9-period-of-time.html

But I don't know how to put it into practice.

That's why I would like to know if there was someone who could help me.

I have already explained above everything that, in my opinion, you need to know and what you are trying to do.